# AngularJS Firebase Structure

Tags: firebase

The below image is of the site I created with the fields that get sent to Firebase.

[image: Web]

This is how its structured in Firebase, which is as expected

[image: Firebase]

I would like to incorporate the drop boxes so they post above the ID, at the minute in my services.js I have the following:
 var ref = new Firebase('leaguesdev.firebaseio.com/League');

But I would like the structure be somthing like

```
leaguesdev.firebaseio.com/League/dropdown1/dropdown2/Club
```

I'm not sure how much or how little you need to see but I will attempt to cover what I think you will want to see

services.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.interviews')
.factory('interviewsService', ['$firebase','$firebaseArray','$q', function($firebase, $firebaseArray, $q) {

        var ref = new Firebase('leagesdev.firebaseio.com/League');

        var getData = function(callback){
            return $firebaseArray(ref);
        };

        var showFalse = function(){
            return false;
        };

        var showTrue = function(){
            return true;
        };
```

index.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-show="authData">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="InterviewsCtrl">
        <div class="col-md-5" ng-show="addFormShow">
            <h3> Add Clubs to Firebase</h3>
            <form name="mainForm" ng-submit="addInterview()" novalidate style="border-color: transparent;">

  <div class="form-group">
              <label>Division</label>
              <select class="form-control" placeholder="Division" ng-model="divisionname" id="dividionname">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Division</option>
                  <option>Premier Division</option>
                  <option>Division 1</option>
                  <option>Division 2</option>
                  <option>Division 3</option>
                  <option>Division 4</option>
              </select></div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Club Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Clubname" ng-model="clubname" id="clubname">
              </div>
```

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/AjJfLTxbUYo